# Currency amount and note optimization in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem is as follows. I have to accumulate two set of currency: `300` and `200`.

The currency notes will only be multiple of `5`. The input can be of any currency note like:

```
20, 20, 25, 50, 40, 5, 40, 40, 40, 30, 25, 5, 50, 50, 40, 20, 25, 25, 25, 30, 20, 20, 20, 20, 45
```

There can be multiple output like

```
Output1:{50, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 25, 25}, {50, 50, 30, 30, 20, 20}
Output2:{50, 50, 40, 40, 20, 40, 40, 20}, {50, 45, 25, 30, 25, 25}
```

How to solve this problem using java. It seems I need to apply dynamic programming approach but I am not able to construct the algorithm properly.

Note: Number of notes is dynamic. Also, maximum note value is not mentioned. Even it can be 200 or 300.

Comment: Do you need all possible answers?? or only one possible is good enough??

Comment: Mention maximum number of currency notes.

Comment: Any possible output @Jishnu. Number is dynamic. It can change. And you may not need to use all the note.

Comment: I know it may change. But if you can tell me the maximum number, its easier to design and calculate the complexity. 

For example, in my solution, if `maxInputSize` is `200`, it takes a memory complexity like `300*200*200=1.2*10^7` which we can afford. But if it's `2000`, then the memory complexity becomes `300*200*2000=1.2*10^8`, which we can't.

Comment: I don't think it's required. Following is my approach
`optimise(list, usedList, amount, remainingAmount){
 if(list contains amount){
  list(key, value) --> usedList(key, value);//moves
  if(remainingAmount>0){
   optimise(list, usedList, remainingAmount, 0)
  }
 }else{
  optimise(list, usedList, amount-5, remainingAmount+5)
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can design this way ->

```
bool dp(int _300, int _200, int cur){
    if(_300==0 and _200==0) return true;
    if(_300<0 or _200<0) return false;
    if(cur>=input.size()) return false;

    if(_300!=0) dp(_300-input[cur], _200, cur+1);
    if(_200!=0) dp(_300, _200-input[cur], cur+1);
    dp(_300, _200, cur);
}
```

I haven't done the `memoization` part and the `printing output` part. But, I guess you can do `memoization` by your own.

And at the time when you know that there's a valid output exists, you can print it from the array.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Let me try it. Thanks

Comment: If you think it helped, then don't forget to accept the answer. @AnirbanB